# Time Delay Margin

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, control-theory, optimal-control

I have a question regarding the time delay margin. I know the definition of time delay margin now I want to know that for the stability of the system is it good to have large time delay margin or small time delay margin?

Answer (score 0):

The delay margin is a measure of robustness (how much delay can be added to the open-loop before it becomes unstable). The closed-loop system should already be stable in order to talk about margins. Why the delay margin can be useful is because a lot of controller applications use a digital implementation, which means AD-converters for the sensors and DA-converters for the actuators. This and the computation of the control logic itself takes time. If were to use a cheaper PLC then this time can increase.

Also it can be noted that the delay margin and phase margin of a closed-loop system are proportional to each other through the bandwidth.